# Dynamically hiding table rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to alternate background colors of table rows, each section starting with the same color. I have achieved this with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("tbody tr.row:nth-child(even)").css("background", "#efefef"); });
```

I also need to be able to limit the number of rows (5 for example) that are visible inside each tbody section. These need to be able to be toggled with a button with a .click() event. Does anyone know how I could achieve this? The only solutions I have come up with caused the background colors to break. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is an example of the table structure:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
    $('#showAll').click(function() {
        $('table > tbody').each(function() {
            $(this).children('tr:gt(4)').toggle();
        });
        $("tr:visible").filter(':odd').css("background", "#efefef").end()
            .filter(':even').css("background", "#ffffff");
    }).click();
});
```

Edited to clean up code (inspired by @karim79's answer).

Comment: This worked well, but with one problem. The last visible tr appears to have no padding, and after the hidden rows are shown, it has normal padding, but the rows that were just shown have double padding. This seems to be a mozilla thing. Do you know what the issue might be?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual CSS and HTML.  It may be the effect of an unintended CSS rule or possible in an invalid table structure.  Note: I updated the answer after I found a bug in the alternating row code.

Comment: When I use rule `table tr { padding: 2px; }` the last row seems to appear properly regardless of visiblity.

Comment: http://www.ktross.com/matrix/

There is my code. Not sure what's going on with it. :(

Answer (score 1):

This does it (tested):

```
var rowLimit = 5;
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('button').click(function() {
        //hide everything after the rowLimit row
        $('table > tbody > tr:gt(' + (rowLimit - 1) + ')').toggle();
     });
 });
```

The key is in the [gt selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt)

To prevent your row styles from vanishing, put them in a CSS class and use addClass and removeClass instead to apply them, bearing in mind that if they're not in a class, then they don't exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling. Set the height of the table to what 5 rows will fit in, and then use css

overflow: scroll; :D

Comment: The rows end up being different sizes, so this unfortunately won't work very well. Thanks for the thought though! :)