# jquery for hiding or showing parent table rows

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a control that can just be dropped in a table to hide or show all rows which the control is not in. Im working on an old app that uses lots of explicit javascript functions to do this per IDs of elements, but wanted to see if it was possible to do with a little jquery. Below links to how you would hide rows of a table but **how would you access that table from the child element?**

[hiding table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296729/dynamically-hiding-table-rows-with-jquery)

I would likely have it as a .net user control, where the jquery would reside, with a hidden field to preserve weather or not the item is set to show or hide on postback, or to explicitly do so based on serverside logic/data. I am kind of new to jquery so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are new, then reading a [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) might help.

Comment: Maybe you want `closest('table')`? Check the docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [closest("table")](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)